# How to combine the following regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

So the basic idea is that I want to split the following into 3 sections, the description text, the html code and the script code:

```
---
name: Accordion
description: |
  ### What
  Puts modules of content into a linear stack of panels that can be closed and opened independently of each other. The accordion also helps in shortening a page and making it more scannable.

  ### Use when
  The content modules are mutually exclusive. Content modules can consist of a list of items, links or text blocks. 
---
<!-- Accordion-->
<div class="ui-accordion">
    some html
</div>
<!-- / Accordion  -->

<script>
some code
</script>
```

Currently I've been able to split it into 2 parts but it also includes the script section which needs to be in the third part.

```
^(-{3}(?:\n|\r)([\w\W]+?)-{3})?([\w\W]*)
```

I tried it this way but *doesnt* work

```
^(-{3}(?:\n|\r)([\w\W]+?)-{3})?([\w\W]*)(<script.*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>)
```

Any suggestions?

The exact output I need is the following:

```
### What
      Puts modules of content into a linear stack of panels that can be closed and opened independently of each other. The accordion also helps in shortening a page and making it more scannable.

      ### Use when
      The content modules are mutually exclusive. Content modules can consist of a list of items, links or text blocks. 

<!-- Accordion-->
<div class="ui-accordion">
    some html
</div>
<!-- / Accordion  -->

some code
```

But it needs to be separated into 3 groups.

Comment: Why you don't use the `<-- / Accordion  -->`?

Comment: It would help if you included the exact output you would like from the example input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:---[\s\n\r]*((?:.|[\n\r\s])*)(?=[\s\r\n]+---)[\s\r\n]+---)?(?:(?=[\n\r\s]+<!--[\s]*Accordion[\s]*-->)[\s\r\n]+<!--[\s*]Accordion[\s]*-->[\s\n\r]*((?:.|[\n\r\s])*)(?=[\s\r\n]*<!--[\s]*\/ Accordion[\s]*-->)[\s\r\n]+<!--[\s]*\/ Accordion[\s]*-->)?(?:(?:.|[\n\r\s])*(?=<script>)<script>[\s\r\n]*((?:.|[\n\r\s])*)(?=[\s\r\n]*<\/script>)[\s\r\n]+<\/script>)?
```

Note that this is strict to a few things in the input (that the comments be wrapped with "---", the comment start/end with ). May need to be tweaked to fit a more liberal match.